# Retrieve Documents from a different drive in C#

Tags: c#

My C# web application resides on the `C` drive.
However the application receives uploaded documents from users and saves them on the `D` drive.

How do I specify the path to documents on the `D` drive in the NavigateUrl property of an HyperLink control in the web application on the `C` drive.

Answer (score 0):

In server-side, you could load the file inside a `Stream` and response this object as a `byte[]`

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    // create a FileStream from a path from local (D:, C:, E:, etc...)
    FileStream file = File.OpenRead(@"d:\folder\yourfile.txt");

    //Convert the stream to an array of bytes.  
    byte[] byteArray = file.ToArray();

    // Clear all content output from the buffer stream
    Response.Clear();

    // Add a HTTP header to the output stream that specifies the default filename
    // for the browser's download dialog
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=foo.txt");

    // Add a HTTP header to the output stream that contains the 
    // content length(File Size). This lets the browser know how much data is being transfered
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", byteArray.Length.ToString());

    // Set the HTTP MIME type of the output stream
    Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";

    // Write the data out to the client.
    Response.BinaryWrite(byteArray);
}
```

Comment: Many thanks Felipe. What i need is how to specify the NavigateUrl property of a Hyperlink to navigate to documents on the D: drive.

Comment: You cannot do this, because you will execute it on the server side, NavigateUrl redirect to an url and in this process, take a file from another drive or folder outside the wwww folder and response to the client-side. You could pass a parameter in the url and process it with a queystring.